# How to download and save the .csv from the url and use it to process in next function using python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, csv

I'm trying to download and process the .csv files and stuck on one thing, below function to process the .csv works perfect.

```
def insertTimeStampcsv():
    rows = []
    with open(r'output.csv', 'w', newline='') as out_file:
        timestamp = datetime.now()        
        df = pd.read_csv(getCsv())
        if 'Name' in df.columns:
            df.rename(columns = {"Name": "team", "Total": "cost"}, inplace = True)
        df.insert(0, 'date',timestamp)
        df.insert(1, 'resource_type', "pod")
        df.insert(2, 'resource_name', "kubernetes")
        df.insert(3, 'cluster_name', "talabat-qa-eks-cluster")
        df.drop(["CPU", "GPU", "RAM", "PV", "Network", "LoadBalancer", "External", "Shared", "Efficiency"], axis=1, inplace=True)
        df["team"] = df["team"].replace(["search-discovery"], "vendor-list")

        df.to_csv(out_file, index=False)
        return df

insertTimeStampcsv()
```

But when it comes to provide the .csv to above function, I'm using another function to generate the .csv using below code but it does not works… any help would be appreciated?

```
from datetime import datetime 
import pandas as pd 
import requests

headers = {
    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
}

params = {
    'window': 'today',
    'aggregate': 'namespace',
    'accumulate': 'false',
    'shareTenancyCosts': 'true',
    'shareNamespaces': 'kube-system,lens-metrics,istio-system,default,newrelic,webhook,cert-manager',
    'shareIdle': 'true',
    'format': 'csv',
}

# temp_file_name = 'input.csv'

def getCsv():
    # result = []
    r = requests.get('http://localhost:9090/model/allocation', headers=headers, params=params)
    lines = r.content
    print(lines)
getCsv()
```

Comment: The `getCsv()` function does not have a `return` statement, so it returns `None` by default.  Perhaps you meant to _return_ lines, instead of _printing_ it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`getCsv()` should rather return a dataframe then you can call it in `insertTimeStampcsv()`. You don't need to open any file in `insertTimeStampcsv()` since `getCsv()` is returning the `df`.

This should allow you to process the CSV file received from the `requests.get` call and save the modified dataframe to the `"output.csv"` file.

**Example:**

```py
def getCsv():
    r = requests.get('http://localhost:9090/model/allocation', headers=headers, params=params)
    with open("input.csv", "w") as f:
        f.write(r.content)
    df = pd.read_csv("input.csv")
    return df
```

```py
def insertTimeStampcsv():
    df = getCsv()
    if 'Name' in df.columns:
        df.rename(columns = {"Name": "team", "Total": "cost"}, inplace = True)
    df.insert(0, 'date', datetime.now())
    df.insert(1, 'resource_type', "pod")
    df.insert(2, 'resource_name', "kubernetes")
    df.insert(3, 'cluster_name', "talabat-qa-eks-cluster")
    df.drop(["CPU", "GPU", "RAM", "PV", "Network", "LoadBalancer", "External", "Shared", "Efficiency"], axis=1, inplace=True)
    df["team"] = df["team"].replace(["search-discovery"], "vendor-list")

    df.to_csv("output.csv", index=False)
    return df

insertTimeStampcsv()
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to use `io.StringIO` than going via a disk file?

Comment: If you can share the example, it would be awesome.

Comment: Thanks @Jamiu for the suggestion, I was able to make it work with small modifications.